# Make the SVG size adjust to the size of the inner text content

Tags: css, html, svg

My SVG contains just a piece of text, and its graphical size is variable, depending on the font used and length of the text.

Is there any way to make the SVG take the width and height of the text graphic?

Right now if I don't specify a size on the SVG , it will be displayed at 300 x 150, cutting off the text and not centering it.

```css
.test {
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

svg {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  object-fit: contain;
  /* nothing :( */
  /*
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  */
}

body {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
  </defs>
  <text class="test" x="50" y="120">sample text</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: svg {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  object-fit: contain;width:100%}

Comment: I want the width and height to be the size of the text graphic, not 100% of the parent element

Comment: Call getBBox to find the size of the text graphic and size the SVG to fit.

Comment: but note that `getBBox` only works *after* you add the SVG to the DOM. If you call it before, you'll get zero values. The simplest solution is to use percent values for the dimensions you need.